# Correct moderator response to a potentially off-target answer?

Tags: discussion, moderators, deleted-answer

I wrote an answer (now deleted by a moderator) to this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91264/what-is-the-biblical-basis-to-prove-the-perpetual-virginity-of-mary/91279#91279) that answered in the negative (the question asks for the biblical basis for doctrine X, and I provided biblical basis against doctrine X). My answer was deleted by a diamond mod with the comment that it was deleted as not answering the question. Is this a valid action? It doesn't give me the recourse to actually correct the perceived problem and let the community vote it up or down to show their agreement or disagreement. My intent after seeing this was to edit the answer to make it more clear what my answer to the question is (since the site lets you edit deleted answers I actually did this, but of course to no effect), but since it's deleted it doesn't matter.

Is this an appropriate course of action by a moderator in a case like this? Wouldn't it be better to give the answer writer a chance to correct the issue, and reserve the mod-hammer for if the answerer declined to do so, or did so so poorly that it was clear that the problem was not going to be resolved?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's exactly why we have moderators - especially here.  Try answering a Jehovah's Witness question with Mormon Doctrine and you'll see why this is necessary!

This:

[What is the Biblical evidence against the perpetual virginity of Mary?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4364/what-is-the-biblical-evidence-against-the-perpetual-virginity-of-mary?rq=1)

is the question you wanted to answer, I believe.

Comment: That question provides evidence of an answer [totally analogous to mine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4367/45377), though on the other side of the fence that was not mod deleted. Was that an incorrect action? If so it should also be deleted.

Comment: To be clear I'm referring to the question you linked, and to the answer linked in my comment. If that answer is appropriate, mine is too (possibly with some clarifying edits which I'd love to be allowed to make). If mine isn't that one should be mod deleted too.

Comment: @Bob, no, that answer is not appropriate - someone ought to have flagged it, not just commented that it was.  You can edit deleted posts and flag to have them reopened, but we're not going to bend on the "answers shouldn't contradict the premise of the question rule" otherwise we'll have chaos (not that we don't have chaos already, but at least we have a few rules that are easy to follow).  If you want to answer a question that isn't asked - feel free to ask the question and answer it yourself.

Comment: So to be clear frame challenges aren't allowed on this site?

Comment: @bob no I can't think of an instance that I'd rather see a frame challenge than the question just be closed.

Comment: The problem I have, and I've looked at this after reading meta posts on what this site is about and why answering an X type question with a Y type answer is not ok, is that the question I answered asked "what is the biblical basis for X", and not "what would a Catholic say is the biblical basis for X", and so I maintain that it is not fundamentally as written a Catholic question but a Bible question, and so non-Catholic viewpoints are in scope. If the question had specifically asked what Catholics believe that would have been different.

Comment: It could of course mean that the question itself is bad and needs to be closed.

Comment: We only begrudgingly allow [tag:biblical-basis] . hidden in the meaning of each of those questions is "according to those who believe ...."  we'd want to close questions where nobody believes a certain thing or it's pretty clear that everyone believes it for a different reason.

Comment: @bob A frame challenge answer to that question would say "Actually Catholics believe Mary did have sex with Joseph." Your answer is not a frame challenge.